# Inner transaction is committed into database, but after that the outer transaction in C# code is rolled back

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am saving an user info from c# code into sql server. The transaction scope is used at both places (C# and SQL Server). Let the user info saved successfully and the transaction is committed in sql but after that due to some error the transaction in c# code is rolled back. Then sql transaction will also be rolled back ?

Comment: Have you written some test code to see what happens?

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. They do NOT even come close to what most people think. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/